# Confusion about outer product in QM

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space

For reference, I am a beginning graduate students. I am familiar with Griffiths and am currently working through the beginning of Sakurai.

I am kind of confused about what the operator $ |a\rangle\langle b|$ is and what it's used for.

I understand that $\langle a|b\rangle$, for example, can be interpreted as how much $b$ "overlaps" with $a$. And if $a$ is an eigenstate of some observable $|\langle a|b \rangle|^2$ is the probability that if you were to measure that observable for a system in state $b$, you would get $a$.

But I am lacking any kind of intuition or physical interpretation of what the operator  $ |a\rangle\langle b|$ might represent.

Sorry if the question is a bit vague or unclear, but any help is appreciated!

Comment: You can sort of view |a> <b| as a matrix element. 
It acts on a vector |c> like so: |a><b|c>
<b|c> is just a scalar, so you obtain <b|c>|a>, which is a vector.

Comment: The outer product is also intimately related to a quantity called the “projector.” Essentially it allows you to project out the components of a wavefunction formed from an LCAO of other wavefunctions.

Comment: It is better to think of $|a><b|$ as a matrix with only one non-zero element, rather than just as a "matrix element." For example, in the two dimensional space spanned by $|->$ and $|+>$ the operator $|-><+|$ corresponds to the matrix $\left(\begin{matrix}0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0\end{matrix}\right)$

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The quantity $|a\rangle\langle b|$ is a linear operator; it sends kets to kets. Linear operators are equivalent to matrices (if the Hilbert space if finite dimensional). This can be seen by writing it out in vector notation. For example:
\begin{align}
|1\rangle\langle2|=\pmatrix{1\\0\\0}\pmatrix{0&1&0}=\pmatrix{0&1&0\\0&0&0\\0&0&0\\}
\end{align}

Another way to think of this operator is to consider the operator in steps. First, when $\langle b|$ consumes a ket , let's say $|\psi\rangle$, it spits out a number that tells you the projection of $|\psi\rangle$ onto $|b\rangle$ up to a complex scalar. Or more simply, it takes the dot product. Then, it takes this scalar and creates a new vector in the direction of $|a\rangle$. Specifically, when $a=b$ the operator becomes a projection (up to a scalar). The operator $\frac{1}{||a||^2}|a\rangle\langle a|$ takes a ket and projects it onto $|a\rangle$.

Finally, note that a matrix can be written as sum of these outer products.
\begin{align}A=&A_{11}|1\rangle\langle 1|+A_{12}|1\rangle\langle 2|+\\
&A_{21}|2\rangle\langle 1|+A_{22}|2\rangle\langle 2|\end{align}
You can easily check this by writing out this expression in matrix notation.

I wish you best of luck in your quantum endeavors.

---

As a final note on what this is used for: it is a quite basic operation in the sense that it is used all over the place. You will encounter it many more times. One of the powers of bra-ket notation is that you can view a concatenation of bra-ket-objects in different ways. For example, you can view $\langle\psi|a\rangle\langle a|\psi\rangle$ as a multiplication of two inner products $(\langle\psi|a\rangle)\cdot(\langle a|\psi\rangle)$ or as a linear operator sandwiched between a bra-ket pair $\langle\psi|(|a\rangle\langle a|)|\psi\rangle$

Answer (score 7):

Probably the easiest way to see what the outer product is to act with it on a state on our Hilbert space. Define the Hilbert space $\mathcal{H}$ and an orthonormal basis on this vector space $\{|e_{i}\rangle\}$. Then any object of the form $|a\rangle\langle b|$ can be expressed as:
\begin{equation}
|a\rangle\langle b| = \sum_{i,j} c_{i,j} |e_{i}\rangle\langle e_{j}|
\end{equation}
Now let us act on this with a wavefunction on our Hilbert space $|\psi\rangle = \sum_{k} b_{k} |e_{k}\rangle$
\begin{equation}
|a\rangle\langle b|\psi\rangle = \sum_{i,j, k} c_{i,j}b_{k} |e_{i}\rangle\langle e_{j}|e_{k}\rangle = \sum_{i,j}b_{j}c_{i,j}|e_{i}\rangle
\end{equation}
What have we done? The action was to map a state to another state i.e. we have an operator! The most important one you will use is the resolution of the identity, where $c_{i,j} = \delta_{ij}$. Then
\begin{equation}
\mathbb{1}|\psi\rangle = \sum_{i, k} b_{k} |e_{i}\rangle\langle e_{i}|e_{k}\rangle = \sum_{i}b_{i}|e_{i}\rangle = |\psi\rangle
\end{equation}
In conclusion the things you are looking at are linear maps from $\mathcal{H}\rightarrow\mathcal{H}$, known as operators. It is useful to express operators as a sum over the outer products of basis states to explicitly evaluate their action on wavefunctions.

Answer (score 6):

In addition to the above nice answer, if you are familiar with relativity then the outer product $ |a\rangle \otimes \langle b|$ (where the symbol $\otimes$ is typicall hidden in QM books) is just a (1,1) tensor.

It acts as a map that feeds on a vector and returns a vector as a result (a linear transformation to say).

For your context the map $ |a\rangle \otimes \langle b|$ tells you what happens to a state $|\psi \rangle$ (i.e., to what state it evolves) once the outer product map acts on it.